# Why should I ever use normal (by value) struct passing over "in" (by readonly reference) passing?

Tags: c#, parameters, reference

One of the newest features of the C# language is the `in` keyword for parameter passing. For example, you can pass a `struct` by reference to a method like this:

```
public void DoSomething(in decimal x)
{
    // ...
}
```

and call like this:

```
DoSomething(x);  // no need to DoSomething(in x);
```

This will pass the reference to the decimal in `readonly` mode, so the caller has nothing to worry about. You can't alter the value of `x` inside the `DoSomething` method, and you do not even need to use "in" in the caller. This is completely transparent.

It seems that it only has advantages, mainly on the performance side (for big structs).

So, my question is: Why should I ever use by value struct passing over `in` (by readonly reference) passing on my methods?

Comment: "It seems that it only has advantages, mainly on the performance side (for big structs)" it looks like the answer.

Comment: may be its adopted from java :))

Comment: I agree with the performance/memory aspect, but more importantly, this is to me a "contract" sort of modifier, like readonly. When not to use it: Perhaps some really odd case where you cannot avoid or want to make explicit that you want to be nasty and mutate the state of the struct within the method, for kicks of for functionality (no useful answer pops to mind here). For me it enters in the "matters of style and convention" area. I do happen to find it a good change, I would have preferred that the language did what in does implicitly and have mutation explicit. but previous code would break

Comment: `So, my question is: Why should I ever use by value struct passing over in (by readonly reference) passing on my methods?` How bit is an `int`? How big is a reference?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Unless there's been something added in a recent version that I'm not familiar with, Java has no mechanisms to pass parameters by reference at all.